# ImportError: No module named flask_wtf.csrf on Windows 7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, windows-7, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm having a hard time setting up a flask project on windows. It works like a charm on mac, but on windows 7 I get this:

```
<module 'ntpath' from 'C:\PYTHON27\LIB\ntpath.pyc'>
ERROR    2015-01-18 17:52:22,927 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Fille\PycharmProjects\Objektia-Marketplace\main.py", line 69, in <module>
    from flask_wtf.csrf import CsrfProtect
ImportError: No module named flask_wtf.csrf
INFO     2015-01-18 18:52:22,938 module.py:718] default: "GET /backends HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

All tested computers (4 yosemite, 1 win7) run the same version of pycharm (3.4.1) with the same versions of all modules (newest). All modules for the configured interpreter on the mac are also installed on the windows machines interpreter. They are running python 2.7.6 since 2.7.9 doesn't work with app engine yet. Also tried 2.7.2 on windows 7 with the same result.

It seems like windows can't find flask_wtf, but it's installed in the same way as on mac (using tools in pycharm). Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you confirm python can find it?  What happens if you run python, and do `import flask_wtf.csrf`

Comment: No error. It works from commandline.

Comment: It looks like your using `wsgi`. Did you also restart the webservice after installing flask?

Comment: Yes. I installed flask weeks ago.